# software center wont open due to killall gnome-software

Tags: 16.04, software-center

I just downloaded Ubuntu 16.04 and went to the software center to install Audacity. I checked in the progress tab to see the progress of the download and the application froze. I exited the software center, and ran `killall gnome-software`, so I could restart the software. I tried restarting software center and it wouldn't open.

I tried:
- Reinstalling the software center, to no avail
- Restarted the computer, to no avail
- Updated all my packages and reinstalled the software center again, to no avail.

I used the software center on the live cd and had no problems. I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

fixed, when i first installed the new package, the old(broken software center) stayed.therefore there was 2 software centers  one was called ubuntu software(which didnt open) and another one called ubuntu software center which was the new one i installed. the new one worked and now it works